# Accept different strings from user and display them using colon as separator using java

Tags: java

Which class should I use to get colon separator? I had tried using `String.join(":",inputs[i])`.This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringsColonSeparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inputs = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            inputs[i] = s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How to get output in form of:

> name 1 : name 2 : name 3 : name 4 : name 5

Comment: You write a loop and print the values, with colons between them. Which part of this is troubling you? --- The loop? Unlikely, since you already have a loop. --- Printing? Unlikely, since you're already printing. --- Print a colon? Unlikely, since you already know how to print text. --- So, I ask again, which part of looping over values and printing them is troubling you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it looks that you are joining the Strings while looping (i.e. inside the for loop). You should use String.join after you have filled the array:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringsColonSeparator  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inputs = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            inputs[i] = s.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(String.join(" : ", inputs)); // join after you fill the array
    }
}
```

Run output:

> Enter a string: name 1
>  Enter a string: name 2
>  Enter a string:
>   name 3
>  Enter a string: name 4
>  Enter a string: name 5
>  name
>   1 : name 2 : name 3 : name 4 : name 5

Comment: Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)